# IE 6.0 : font failure error while parsing styles

Tags: internet-explorer-6

Error parsing styles
Internet Explorer 6.0

```
line 9  { font-family:"Neo Sans"; src:('../fonts/Neo_Sans_Medium.eot'); src: local('ufonts.com_neo-sans-medium'), local('ufonts'), url('fonts/Neo_Sans_Medium.ttf') format('truetype'); }
```

Comment: it is not wise to work on IE6 compatibility these days . . Even Microsoft has stopped working on the support for this version - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `@fontface`

```
@font-face {
          font-family:"Neo Sans"; 
          src:('../fonts/Neo_Sans_Medium.eot'); 
          src: local('ufonts.com_neo-sans-medium'), 
               local('ufonts'), 
               url('fonts/Neo_Sans_Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```